# Get the largest key in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, search, key, binary-search

I have a dictionary with keys that are ints. I would like to get the largest key. I don't keep track of keys so they might be consecutive (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6) but might skip (1,3,4,5) although I doubt that makes any difference.

Do I just use a binary search or is there a method? As far as I see you can hardly beat binary search for such a simple task - maybe you can halve it.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted so a binary search would do you little good.

Comment: @AustinSalonen `Dictionary<K, V>` is not sorted, but it bears mention that there are a few ordered implementations of `IDictionary<K, V>` out there.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you have LINQ available, you should be able to do:

```
myDictionary.Keys.Max();
```

Comment: To anyone trying to use this, you'll need to ensure you include the linq extension methods `Imports System.Linq` & compile in .net 3.5+ - Works a treat then :)

Comment: is this of order `O(n)` or of `O(1)`?

Comment: @Pixel_95: O(n). For O(1) you can keep track of the max as the dictionary changes, like in Simon Mourier’s answer.

Answer (score 11):

A binary search would be the fastest but wouldn't work against a normal dictionary, since the Keys aren't stored in any particular order.  @Minitech's answer, using Linq `Max()`, is the easiest if you're using a normal dictionary.

If this is an operation you will have to do many times, you may consider moving to a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which sorts entries based on the key.

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, int> {{3, 0}, {12, 0}, {32, 0}, 
                                           {2, 0}, {16, 0}, {20, 0}};
Console.WriteLine(dict.Keys.Last()); //prints 32
```

EDIT:  This *can be slower* than a normal dictionary.  I suppose it would have been good to mention that.  That's because the entries in the dictionary are stored in a different way (a Red/Black tree vs hash buckets/hash table)

There **is** a point that the `SortedDictionary` becomes faster than a normal `Dictionary`.  However, this would probably come out to be around 1 million items, however that's just a guess.  It turns out it about 10 times faster at that many items (but we're talking about 100ths of a second anyway, so does it *really* matter?).  It's about equal on x64 release for 100000 items.  Considering there's extra overhead of adding items to the dictionary, it's probably not worth it.  Also, I "cheated" a little by overriding the comparer so it would sort in reverse order, so I'm actually doing `dict.Keys.First()` instead of last to get the largest item.

A SortedDictionary is really meant for if you needed to iterate over all of the Key Value pairs in order.  I think @SimonMourier's answer is probably the best.  I guarantee you it's the fastest, with minimal overhead.

Comment: Since the dictionary is sorted, the following code can be also used: `dict.Last().Key;`

Answer (score 3):

If performance is really an issue, I would create a new class on top of an existing one, implementing the standard interfaces, like this:

```
    public class RememberMaxDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V> where K: IComparable<K>
    {
        private Dictionary<K, V> _inner;

        public RememberMaxDictionary()
        {
            _inner = new Dictionary<K, V>();
        }

        public K MaxKey { get; private set; }

        public void Add(K key, V value)
        {
            _inner.Add(key, value);

            if (key.CompareTo(MaxKey) > 0) // test null if needed
            {
                MaxKey = key;
            }
        }

    ... TODO implement the rest...
```

Comment: This is misleading. You left out the part where MaxKey is decreased (assuming removing an entry is desired, which in most cases it is). 'Remove' method is non-trivial to implement in an efficient manner.

Comment: @Dixtosa - depends on your context and needs. Write your own answer.