# VB.NET How to get Max highest element value from a list that's inside a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, max

I got a dictionary which is a `KeyValuePair` of Byte as key and List of uintegers as value

```
Dim items As New Dictionary(Of Byte, List(Of UInteger))
items.Add(1, New List(Of UInteger)(New UInteger() {6, 68, 238, 768, 23484, 23, 7573, 12737, 76579}))
items.Add(54, New List(Of UInteger)(New UInteger() {68768, 2347, 1237, 76878, 1238, 57882391}))
items.Add(5, New List(Of UInteger)(New UInteger() {66, 787, 2883, 1189, 5, 934, 4568, 199999, 500000}))
```

I want to extract the largest UInteger by checking all the entries in the dictionary.
I want to do this in 1 line of code and using the standard commands no external libraries.

yeah it should return the value `57882391`

Here is what I tried so far.

```
Dim TheBiggestUInt as UInteger = items.Where(Function(x As List(Of UInteger)) x.Item = items.Max(Function(y As List(Of UInteger)) y.Item))
Dim TheBiggestUInt as UInteger = items.Where(Function(x As List(Of UInteger)) x = items.Max(Function(y As List(Of UInteger)) y))
Dim TheBiggestUInt as UInteger = items.Values.Where(Function(x As List(Of UInteger)) x = items.Max(Function(y As List(Of UInteger)) y))
```

I get a error

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)))' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)))' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Max' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger))(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger))) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger))'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Decimal?)) As Decimal?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Decimal?'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Decimal)) As Decimal' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Decimal'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Double?)) As Double?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Double?'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Double)) As Double' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Double'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Single?)) As Single?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Single?'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Single)) As Single' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Single'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Long?)) As Long?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Long?'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Long)) As Long' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Long'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Integer?)) As Integer?' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Integer?'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Max(selector As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Byte, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)), Integer)) As Integer' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
```

My best attempt with the least errors

```
Dim TheBiggestUInt as UInteger = items.Values.Where(Function(x As List(Of UInteger)) x = items.Values.Max(Function(y As List(Of UInteger)) y))

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger), Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger))' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger), Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger), Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger))' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of UInteger)'.
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315154/get-the-largest-key-in-a-dictionary

Comment: yeah I seen that one, it didn't help me I have a bunch of lists not a single value

Comment: `items.Values.Max(AddressOf Enumerable.Max)` should *probably* do it

Comment: yup that did it.. you should write that as a answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find the max value from each inner list ; you can get it by first getting the maximum for each inner list and then the max of those maximums.

```
items.Values.Max(AddressOf Enumerable.Max)
```

Alternate syntax using a lambda instead of a method group :

```
items.Values.Max(Function(innerList) innerList.Max)
```