# Largest key of nested dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Tried searching online. But couldn't find an answer:

```
public class A
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Dict { get; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}

var list = new List<A>();
var a = new A();
a.Dict.Add(1, "A");

var b = new A();
b.Dict.Add(2, "A");

list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);
```

How to get the maximum and minimum key in dictionary.

max key is 2 and min key is 1.

```
var max = list.Max(e => e.Dict.??); //
```

Comment: `list.Max(e => e.Dict.Max(e1=>e1.Key));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the largest key in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315154/get-the-largest-key-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: There is no way to do this efficiently, if you are interested for efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Dictionary.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1) property for this:

```
var max = list.Max(e => e.Dict.Keys.Max())
```

or

```
var max = list.SelectMany(e => e.Dict.Keys).Max()
```